# Overwhelmed by layouts, what are my alternatives to make a layout like this, but dynamic number of items?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I'm a flutter user trying out kotlin dev first time, but im kinda confused what the best alternatives for this type of layouts are.

I understand that I use recyclerview for a dynamic number of items. And since theres two dynamic ones (one for number of sets, one for each exercise). Do I use two nested recyclerviews?

Comment: yes lookin at your UI looks like it is recyclerview with each item has horizontal recyclerview

Comment: If it isn't too late to switch to another UI system, I recommend using Android's Jetpack Compose UI instead of layout and the view UI system, it is so much closer to the Flutter UI

Comment: @AhmadHamwi wouldn't the "standard" way of doing it be best to start with if you're considering a job later?

Comment: @Jocko yeah of course, an Android developer definatley should know about the view system, and alot of people are still using it in their apps untill now too. But for a Flutter developer starting with Android, Compose can be a little bit more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're doing here. A `RecyclerView` is basically a list, so it's a good choice for a scrollable set of items - which it looks like your *Exercises* are. But how do you want to display those weights?

It's possible to make them scrollable, so some of them aren't visible on the screen (the categories on the Play Store act like this). For that you would need a nested *scrolling view* of some kind - could be a horizontal `RecyclerView`, or it could just be a `ScrollView` wrapped around a `LinearLayout` you throw views into.

But the other option you might want, is that for each Exercise, all of its weights are visible in a grid of some kind. No scrolling, all there up-front to see and poke at. So the first question is which of those do you want?

I'd assume it's this version - where you can easily visualise the contents - in which case you're not talking about nested lists, it's just one list, and each item contains a grid you can add things too. For that setup, there's [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout), [`TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout), and [`ConstraintLayout Flow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) (which acts like FlexBox if you're familiar with that). So in the layout for an item in your list, you have a container for stuff, and you put the stuff in it, and the container expands vertically as needed